# Laravel Livewire - How to force parent component refresh?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'd like to refresh the parent component when the child is updated.

I have a component 'base.blade.php' and in that file, there is a cart Count section.
and  it called in the child like this in the render function:

```
return view('livewire.admin-dashboard')->layout('layouts.base');
```

when increase and decrease the number of the products, the child component needs to Update the cart info in the base blade file.
how can I do it?

best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

child livewire

```
function increment() {
    $this->emit('reRenderParent');
}
```

parent component

```
protected $listeners = ['reRenderParent'];

public function reRenderParent()
{
    $this->mount();
    $this->render();
}
```

Comment: but the parent has not a component.
it called in the child like this:
return view('livewire.admin.admin-dashboard-component')->layout('layouts.base');

Comment: @RayanFar Please add all the relavent code.

Answer (score 5):

Parent Component

```
protected $listeners = [
  'refreshParent' => '$refresh',
];
```

Child Component

```
public function save(){
    ... //your update code

    $this->emitUp('refreshParent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified and updated response for Livewire 3

**Child component:**

```
class ChildComponent extends Component
{
    function refreshParent() {
        $this->dispatch('refreshParentComponent');
    }
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
class ParentComponent extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = [
        'refreshParentComponent' => '$refresh',
    ];
}
```

`refreshParentComponent` is the name of the event. In Livewire 3, events are dispatched using browser events and therefore will "bubble up" to the parent components by default. Therefore there is no need for specific `emitUp` calls in Livewire 3.

See more information in the [documentation](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events).
And also see the changes made regarding this in the [upgrade guide](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#events).